# Is there a field $K[\alpha]$ with $\alpha$ idempotent?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

I have a field $K$ and an idempotent element $\alpha\not\in K$ (i.e., $\alpha^2=\alpha$), and I would like to form the ring $K[\alpha]$. Can this structure exist (1) in general and (2) with $K=\mathbb{C}$?

It's one thing to mod out $\alpha^2+1$ but modding out (the reducible) $\alpha^2-\alpha$ seems very unusual. (At the risk of repeating myself, $0\ne\alpha\ne1$.)

Comment: It can exist, but it's not a field. That's alright though.

Comment: What is "unusual" about modding out by $\,x^2-x?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: It's reducible in $K$ but its root isn't among the roots of that polynomial. I dunno, maybe I'm just used to algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ and wanted to check in case I was doing something dumb.

Comment: If you think of $$\alpha=\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}$$ then $K[\alpha]$ becomes the ring of diagonal $2\times2$ matrices. Which is isomorphic to the product ring $K\times K$ from Pedro's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking of constructing $K[X]/(X^2-X)$ This is just $K\times K$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. That's as general as it gets, since any other structure you're thinking factors through this. This is not a field, of course, since it has nontrivial idempotents, but fields, in general domains, only have the trivial ones: $0,1$.

Comment: Good -- that's what I was thinking, but I wanted a double-check. It's certainly a strange structure.

Comment: @Charles It's a product ring. Those are really not *that* strange.

Comment: I mean, it's a strange way to think of a product ring. :)